# Rails Has Many relation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have two models that two relationships between them

```
class Tracking
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :origin_courier, :class_name => "Courier", foreign_key: "origin_courier_id"
  belongs_to :destination_courier, :class_name => "Courier", foreign_key: "destination_courier_id"

end

class Courier
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :origins, class_name: 'Tracking', foreign_key: "origin_courier_id"
  has_many :destinations, class_name: 'Tracking', foreign_key: "destination_courier_id"
end
```

When I assign a courier to the origin_courier of a newly created tracking, it run fine.

```
1.9.3p194 :015 > t = Tracking.new
 => #<Tracking _id: 4fbcc2772cfb397930000003, _type: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, origin_courier_id: nil, destination_courier_id: nil> 
1.9.3p194 :016 > t.origin_courier = Courier.last
 => #<Courier _id: 4fbcbb072cfb397657000004, _type: nil, created_at: 2012-05-23 10:25:11 UTC, updated_at: 2012-05-23 10:25:11 UTC> 
1.9.3p194 :017 > t
 => #<Tracking _id: 4fbcc2772cfb397930000003, _type: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, origin_courier_id: BSON::ObjectId('4fbcbb072cfb397657000004'), destination_courier_id: nil> 
1.9.3p194 :018 > t.save
 => true 
1.9.3p194 :019 > t
 => #<Tracking _id: 4fbcc2772cfb397930000003, _type: nil, created_at: 2012-05-23 10:57:14 UTC, updated_at: 2012-05-23 10:57:14 UTC, origin_courier_id: BSON::ObjectId('4fbcbb072cfb397657000004'), destination_courier_id: nil>
```

But when I assign a courier to the destination_courier of a newly created tracking, it duplicates the value to origin_courier

```
1.9.3p194 :020 > t2 = Tracking.new
 => #<Tracking _id: 4fbcc3002cfb397930000004, _type: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, origin_courier_id: nil, destination_courier_id: nil> 
1.9.3p194 :021 > t2.destination_courier = Courier.last
 => #<Courier _id: 4fbcbb072cfb397657000004, _type: nil, created_at: 2012-05-23 10:25:11 UTC, updated_at: 2012-05-23 10:25:11 UTC> 
1.9.3p194 :022 > t2.save
 => true 
1.9.3p194 :023 > t2
 => #<Tracking _id: 4fbcc3002cfb397930000004, _type: nil, created_at: 2012-05-23 11:00:39 UTC, updated_at: 2012-05-23 11:00:39 UTC, origin_courier_id: BSON::ObjectId('4fbcbb072cfb397657000004'), destination_courier_id: BSON::ObjectId('4fbcbb072cfb397657000004')>
```

How can I resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Very strange. Have you tried Courier.last.origins << Tracking.new and Courier.last.destinations << Tracking.new ?

Comment: @soundar it is still the same case...don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/2038

It is bug of Mongoid.
Durran has fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

(You mixed new Hash notaion (1.9.3) with older one in `Tracking`)

Did you try `inverse_of` instead of `foreign_key` ?

```
class Tracking
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :origin_courier, class_name: "Courier", inverse_of: :origins
  belongs_to :destination_courier, class_name: "Courier", inverse_of: :destinations

end
```

and

```
class Courier
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :origins, class_name: 'Tracking', inverse_of: :origin_courier
  has_many :destinations, class_name: 'Tracking', inverse_of: :destination_courier
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Echo "very strange,"

The following modification also works, and I present it only because it might shed some light on the underlying problem.

```
class Courier
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :origin_trackings, class_name: "Tracking", foreign_key: :origin_tracking_id
  has_many :destination_trackings, class_name: "Tracking", foreign_key: :destination_tracking_id
end
```

But I recommend NOT using **foreign_key** and DO second the recommendation to use **inverse_of** by Maxime Garcia.

For **has_many/belongs_to**, the relationship only has to be tracked on one side, even if the relationship is defined on both sides,
So like Active Record, Mongoid chooses for you, in this case to efficiently put the single link into the Tracking instance,
rather than growing an array of links in the Courier instance.

But a possible collision on foreign_key origin_courier_id for Tracking and Courier (or on foreign_key destination_courier_id for Tracking and Courier)
should not result in confusion between origin_* and destination_*.
I've looked at the metadata, which is only available for links that are set, and the metadata looks OK.
It's certainly a strange problem that would be interesting to investigate further as time and priorities permit.
Anyone else have some insight or knowledge of Mongoid internals?